# variant of Heine-Borel theorem : countable subcovering of segment covering in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If in $\mathbb R$ one has an inclusion $[a,b]\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} (a_i,b_i)$,
then the Heine-Borel theorem tells us that a finite subcover exists :
$[a,b]\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I'} (a_i,b_i)$ for some finite $I'\subseteq I$.
Suppose now that the covering is made of segments instead of open intervals :
$[a,b]\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} [a_i,b_i]$. Then we cannot expect a finite
subcovering (consider for example 
$[0,1]\subseteq [1,2] \cup \bigcup_{k\geq 1} 
[1-\frac{1}{2^{2k-3}},1-\frac{1}{2^{2k}}]$), but I ask if there is always
a **countable** subcovering ?

My (unsuccessful) thoughts : if the property is true, it seems like some 
form of the axiom of choice is needed. 
If some $x$ is in three distinct segments of the covering, then one of those
three segments is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq [a,b]$ be the union of the intersections of $[a,b]$ with the open intervals $(a_i,b_i)$.  Writing this relatively  open set as the countable union of compact subsets, we find a countable cover of $A$ by $(a_i,b_i)$ and therefore by your segments.
Anything in $[a,b] \backslash A$ is the left or right endpoint of one of your
segments.  Let $B = [a,b] \cap \{a_i: i \in I\} \backslash A$ and 
$C = [a,b] \cap \{b_i: i \in I\} \backslash A$, so $[a,b] = A \cup B \cup C$.  We can write $B = \bigcup_n B_n$ where $B_n = [a,b] \cap \{a_i: i \in I, b_i - a_i > 1/n\}  \backslash A$.
Now if $b, b' \in B_n$, we must have $|b - b'| \ge 1/n$, so $B_n$ is finite and $B$ is countable, and thus is covered by countably many segments.  Similarly $C$ is countable and is covered by countable many segments.

Comment: "the countable union of compact subsets" (of $A$ I presume) ; but there are uncountably many compact subsets of $A$, aren't they ?

Comment: Doesn't matter.  Explicitly e.g. you can take $K_n = \{x: \text{dist}(x, A^c) \ge 1/n\}$.

Comment: Ok, so you really meant "writing this relatively open set as A countable union"

Comment: I think the article "the" is still appropriate: it is *the* union of *a* family of compact sets. Either article works.